# Tomcat Websockets and hazelcast clusterization

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, hazelcast

I have web service(service A), that should be clustered on different instances. It is ServerEndpoint and has socket communications with number of another services(services group B) and RESTful API(for service C).

I have a problem - I need to store all socket connections with B-services on A-service, and after service C makes API call to the A-service, it should return the best option from B group.

But I don't know how should I store websocket.Session objects using Hazelcast? Session objects are not serializable. Maybe I should reinit session by session ID on other cluster instances if needed?

Comment: edit: [tag:cluster-analysis] (aka clustering, a data mining technique is not the same thing as [tag:load-balancing] on multiple servers.